# Placing secure data in Java web application

Tags: java, security

This post is complementary to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863186/placing-secure-data-in-java-web-application/30867508?noredirect=1#comment49831787_30867508)
I asked the question about implementing DropBox's "Share link" functionality on the server side in the most "secure" way. Of course, real security involves at least password-based authentication, not this "security by obscurity" approach, but the guys from DropBox managed to implement this somehow :)

Here is the code I've written for this task. I would be grateful for any comments and criticism for this small piece of code.

```
package com.test;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Anton P. Kolosov
 */
public class ObscureSecureServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Pattern UUID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^[A-F0-9]{8}(?:-[A-F0-9]{4}){3}-[A-F0-9]{12}$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    private String basePath;

    /**
     * Initialization routines
     * @param config Servlet configuration
     * @throws ServletException
     */
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

        super.init(config);

        basePath = config.getInitParameter("basePath");
    }

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String res = request.getParameter("res");
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        Matcher matcher = UUID_PATTERN.matcher(res);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            // Only UUIDs are allowed for res parameter
            File file = new File(basePath + "/" + res, name);
            if (file.exists()) {
                sendFile(file, request, response);
                return;
            }
        }

        // Can redirect to jsp if you wish...
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>File not found</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("File for res = " + res + " and name = " + name + " was not found!");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    private void sendFile(File file, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        long fileSize = file.length();
        response.setHeader("Content-length", Long.toString(fileSize));
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" );
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(out);

        write(file, bufferedOutputStream);
        bufferedOutputStream.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Writes a document to the passed stream.
     * @param bufferedOutput The method writes name to this output stream
     * @throws IOException IOException
     */
    public void write(File file, BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutput) throws IOException {
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024 * 4];
        BufferedInputStream  bufferedInput = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            int lengthRead = 0;
            int offset = 0;
            while (true) {
                lengthRead = bufferedInput.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                if (lengthRead == -1) {
                    break;
                }

                bufferedOutput.write(buffer, 0, lengthRead);
                offset += lengthRead;
            }
        } finally {
            if (bufferedInput != null) {
                bufferedInput.close();
            }
        }
    }


    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Servlet for 'obscure secure' file retrieving";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Answer (score 10):

You check that `res` must match a specific pattern, but `name` seems to be free game. What if a user calls this with values like:

- `../../../../etc/passwd`
- `../../../../../../home/jack/.ssh/id_rsa`
- ...

Avoid concatenating path segments with / separator. Let the two-argument constructor of `File` do that for you. If you have three path segments then use an intermediary file insurance.

You used try-with-resources nicely in `processRequest` but not in other places. It would be good to use that technique everywhere when working with closeable resources.

Answer (score 5):

It's something of a nitpick, but you have

> ```
>     public void write(File file, BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutput) throws IOException {
>         byte buffer[] = new byte[1024 * 4];
>         BufferedInputStream  bufferedInput = null;
>         try {
>             FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
>             bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
>             int lengthRead = 0;
>             int offset = 0;
>             while (true) {
>                 lengthRead = bufferedInput.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
>                 if (lengthRead == -1) {
>                     break;
>                 }
>
>                 bufferedOutput.write(buffer, 0, lengthRead);
>                 offset += lengthRead;
>             }
>         } finally {
>             if (bufferedInput != null) {
>                 bufferedInput.close();
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

which you call

> ```
>         ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
>         BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
>
>         write(file, bufferedOutputStream);
>         bufferedOutputStream.flush();
> ```

I personally find it confusing for that method to be called `write` when most of its logic is about reading from `file`.  Perhaps change its name to `echo` and call it like

```
        echo(file, response.getOutputStream());
```

Then the method itself would change to

```
    public void echo(File in, ServletOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        BufferedInputStream  bufferedInput = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutput = null;

        try {
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024 * 4];
            bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(out);

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(in);
            bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

            int lengthRead = bufferedInput.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            while (lengthRead != -1) {
                bufferedOutput.write(buffer, 0, lengthRead);
                lengthRead = bufferedInput.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            }
        } finally {
            if (bufferedInput != null) {
                bufferedInput.close();
            }

            if (bufferedOutput != null) {
                // we don't want to close the ServletOutputStream
                // so we just flush here
                bufferedOutput.flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

It makes more sense to me to have a method that handles both input and output streams called `echo`.  Also note that I moved more of the output related logic into the method.  This puts the input and output operations on a more level footing.

Added a comment explaining why we call `flush` rather than `close`.  Hopefully I followed the logic there correctly.  If not, then I think that highlights why that decision should be commented.

I removed `offset`, as it was generated but never used.

I changed the `while (true)` to remove the `break` statement.  It's a matter of personal preference, but I find this version easier to read.  The other version is generally fine.

Another variant would be

```
            int lengthRead = 0;
            while ((lengthRead = bufferedInput.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                bufferedOutput.write(buffer, 0, lengthRead);
            }
```

Which has the advantage that it avoids duplicate code.  But I find that harder to follow, as it's rather busy.

Comment: Thanks for good refactoring proposal, added it to the corrected version!